# Modified Bessel function of first kind

Tags: sequences-and-series, bessel-functions

While reading a research article, I come accros this expression:
$$
{\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\frac{{p - \sqrt {{p^2} - {\alpha ^2}} }}{{\alpha \beta }}} \right)} ^m} = \frac{\lambda }{{{\beta ^{m + 1}}}}\left[ {{I_{m - 1}}\left( {\alpha \left( t \right)} \right) - {I_{m + 1}}\left( {\alpha \left( t \right)} \right)} \right]{e^{ - \left( {\lambda  + \mu } \right)t}},$$
where

- $p = s + \lambda  + \mu$ ,
- $\alpha  = 2\sqrt {\lambda \mu } $  ,and
- $\beta  = \sqrt {\frac{\lambda }{\mu }} $.

Please help me how they arrived this expression

Comment: Could you give a link to the paper ?

Comment: There is an index issue. The summation is over index $m$, which in essence, would eliminate all terms involving $m$. The right-hand side should not contain $m$.

Comment: @Claude leibovici..Plz give me your Email ID. I will send you the paper.

Comment: It is in my profile. Waiting for it ! Cheers